# iReport variable expression returns null

Tags: jasper-reports

Here's the simple code in XML view of print form:

```
<variable name="TITLE" class="java.lang.String">
     <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{APP_NUMBER}.replaceAll( "app_", "" )]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

If I use this variable in form, it returns null (while using "`$V{TITLE}`"). But if I remove replaceAll method, it works and returns correct value.
What is wrong with expression? Should I use something instead of "`<variableExpression>`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are printing this variable in Title band change its evaluation time to "Report"

```
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        **<textField evaluationTime="Report">**
            <reportElement x="143" y="43" width="100" height="30" uuid="4fc0ce80-ced5-448e-bdd1-1571b3bc788f"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TITLE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
```